# How to convert UIView drawing to GLKView on swift?

Tags: swift, iphone, opengl

I need to convert the drawing image code in UIView to the code in GLKView.

I had implemented 2D avatar player with 30fps in UIView. But the app is very slow and the animation is not smooth. I received a suggestion that convert it to openGL. But I have no experience with openGL. I already changed the custom UIView to GKLView. The issue is just how to convert  transform of CGContext to transform of CIContext.

// context : CGContext

```
var transForm = CGAffineTransform.identity
transForm = transForm.translatedBy(x: CGFloat(dx * scale), y: CGFloat(dy * scale))
transForm = transForm.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(scale), y: CGFloat(scale))
transForm = transForm.rotated(by: CGFloat(-dang ))
transForm = transForm.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(scaleX), y: CGFloat(scaleY))
transForm = transForm.translatedBy(x: CGFloat(-ox + vdw / 2), y: CGFloat(-oy + vdh / 2))
transForm = transForm.scaledBy(x: CGFloat(fh), y: CGFloat(-fv))
context.concatenate(transForm)
let src:CGRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(sx), y: CGFloat(sy), width: CGFloat(sw), height: CGFloat(sh))
let dest:CGRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(-vdw/2), y: CGFloat(-vdh/2), width: CGFloat(vdw), height: CGFloat(vdh))
let cropedImage:CGImage! = img.cropping(to: src)
context.draw(cropedImage, in: dest, byTiling: false);
```

Comment: can you move `let cropedImage:CGImage! = img.cropping(to: src)` this out of drawing and use a cached image directly.

Comment: Thanks , E.Coms. But the code is in for loop. It will be changed every loop.
Or is there any way to draw only image of specific region?

Comment: why do crop? maybe you just need clip to mask?

Comment: clip? how to should I use it?